# Install mysql through deb file on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, installation, ubuntu, debian

Hi I've downloaded the file `mysql-server_8.0.21-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb-bundle.tar` from mysql site.
I've extracted it to see below list of deb files

```
libmysqlclient21_8.0.21-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
libmysqlclient-dev_8.0.21-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
mysql-client_8.0.21-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
mysql-common_8.0.21-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
mysql-community-client_8.0.21-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
mysql-community-client-core_8.0.21-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
mysql-community-server_8.0.21-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
mysql-community-server-core_8.0.21-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
mysql-community-server-debug_8.0.21-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
mysql-community-test_8.0.21-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
mysql-community-test-debug_8.0.21-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
mysql-server_8.0.21-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
mysql-testsuite_8.0.21-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
```

Using mysql to build a web project.

I want to understand

1. what each file is for
2. what order should be followed to install them
3. what files can be skipped
4. any disadvantage of installing through deb file (coming from windows background)
5. is this server edition suitable in prod env as well (short answer is ok)

I've already installed mysql workbench through a deb file

**PS:
I found the dependency among most of these files that helped me install them in order as below:**

i had to install **libaio1** **libmecab2** first

```
sudo dpkg-preconfigure mysql-community-server_*.deb
    mysql-community-client-core
    mysql-community-client
    mysql-client
    mysql-community-server-core
    mysql-community-server
    mysql-server
```

this link was helpful
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/8.0/en/linux-installation-debian.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
 mysql-server_8.0.21-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
```

But yoz should follow the howto

**Install short Howto**

1. Download latest mysql-apt-config deb from

   `https://repo.mysql.com/`
2. Install mysql-apt-config deb:

   `# sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_*.deb`
3. Update the package index:

   `# sudo apt-get update`
4. Install mysql-server deb package:

   `# sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

ANd if you have problems see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/8.0/en/linux-installation-debian.html